# How can I make a reference humidity environment with NaOH pellets?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions, home-experiment

I have NaOH pellets at my disposal. Some of the pellets [are degraded](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71351/how-can-i-estimate-how-much-humidity-is-present-in-a-naoh-granulate), but most are not, and I can provide a new batch if needed.

I would like to test several humidity sensors in an environment with a humidity value around 10%. NaOH should be able to reach [about 7% humidity when pure](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ie50477a041).

How should I proceed? I have tupperware and a stone mortar and pestle, if needed.

Should I take some good pellets, crush them without making them too fine, and place the resulting powder in a container, which I will enclose in the tupperware together with the sensors? or should I place the pellets in water but leaving the solution oversaturated (undissolved pellets visible in the water)?

The pellets would probably have a much higher contact surface with air, but time is not an issue, I can leave the sensors in the container for a day, if needed. Accuracy of the result is more important.

I can tolerate 2-3% errors.

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/112915/35806

Comment: @Poutnik that question has the answer I am looking for: pellets in water should work perfectly.